# React Native - How to load image from local path on WebView

Tags: react-native, webview

I'm looking for how to load an image on a WebView from a local path. It's for insert it on a Callout of MapView (issue on android). When I use an url that work well but nothing with local path.

```
<WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{html: '<Body><img id="logo" src="../../assets/img.jpg" onload="onLoad()" /></Body>'}}
/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried several options, the only thing which works is:

1) creating an index.html file, where you can use your regular image path :

```
<html>
    <body>
    <img src="./dog.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </body> 
</html>
```

2) load the index.html file in your `WebView`

```
<WebView
originWhitelist={['*']}
source={require('./index.html')}
/>
```

By the way, my project is structured like this:

[image]

Things I tried which **do not** work:

```
<WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{html: `<Body><img id="logo" width=200 height=200 src="./dog.jpg" /></Body>`}}
/>

<WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{html: `<Body><img id="logo" width=200 height=200 src="require('./dog.jpg')" /></Body>`}}</Body>`}}
/>

import dog from './dog.jpg'
<WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{html: `<Body><img id="logo" width=200 height=200 src="${dog}" /></Body>`}}
/>
```

Comment: Yes that work well, thanks you! I suppose that's impossible to set dynamically the path of the image (I have no experience in web dev ) ? I cannot use javascript on html file?

Comment: And if the image is on the same folder than the .html that work but if on other folder that doesn't work.

Comment: this solution doesn't seem to work for me.  I get an "Invalid call at line XX: require(this.state.index)"

Comment: @ekkis you need to add code. Therefore I would recommend to ask a new question. Feel free to ping me, so that i can i have look. Thanks

Comment: @Tim, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60371739/webview-refuses-to-display-images

Comment: An alternative solution is to load as base64, if possible 
url('data:image/png;base64,iVBOR=....')